# Is it possible to adjust the swipe angle threshold with ViewPager / ViewPagerAndroid?

Tags: android, react-native

I have a [ViewPager](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-viewpager) (formerly [ViewPagerAndroid](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/viewpagerandroid.html)) within a vertical ScrollView with additional content. I find that when trying to swipe to the next page of the ViewPager, I sometimes end up scrolling vertically instead. It seems that these mis-swipes have an angle that is not close enough to horizontal. Experimentally, I've found that this threshold is less than 45 degrees. Can this be tuned in any way so that any swipe angle less than 45 degrees will move the ViewPager and not the ScrollView?

The following code demonstrates the issue. The line on each page is 45 degrees. Swiping along it scrolls vertically. It's necessary to swipe at a significantly more horizontal angle to get the ViewPager to swipe.

I've also tried this without the enclosing ScrollView, and the ViewPager responds (or doesn't respond) in the same way.

```
/**
 * ViewPager within ScrollView demo
 *
 * @flow
 */

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import ViewPager from "@react-native-community/viewpager";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  viewPager: {
      height: 200,
  },
  page: {
      height: 200,
      borderColor: 'green',
      borderWidth: 1,
  },
  angledLine: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    height: 1,
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    transform: ([
      { rotateZ: '-45deg' },
      { perspective: 1000 },
    ]),
  },
});

const Page = ({ index }) => (
    <View style={styles.page}>
      <View style={styles.angledLine} />
      <Text>{`page ${index}`}</Text>
    </View>
);

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <ViewPager style={styles.viewPager} initialPage={10}>
          { range(20).map(i => <Page key={i} index={i}/>) }
        </ViewPager>
        { range(50).map(i => <Text key={i}>{`line ${i}`}</Text>) }
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

function range(n) {
  const array = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    array.push(i);
  }
  return array;
}
```

Comment: apply link https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/viewpagerandroid

Comment: You try to use `onPageScroll` and `onPageScrollStateChanged`.

Comment: The onPageScroll methods won't help, because the ViewPager isn't even getting to the point of responding to the swipe.